# The match now starts next Monday

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, adverbs, time

I cannot find an appropriate paraphrase for the next sentence, from Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, pag. 133.

*The match now starts next Monday, not Tuesday, as I said in my last letter.*

I'd foreground the adverb to the beginning of the sentence, on the lines of

***Now*** (it so happens that) the match starts next Monday

Furthermore, the last comma only adds ambiguity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [At that stage the match didn’t start till next Tuesday](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/450841/at-that-stage-the-match-didn-t-start-till-next-tuesday)

Comment: This is a duplicate, as stated. You should not pose a new question if you want to expand on the original. Instead, edit the original. In this case, while the two questions you asked are *literally* different, they are so closely related that they could be answered as part of a single answer.

Comment: *The start day of the match has been changed to next Monday.*

Comment: @JasonBassford Care to make that an answer? I would upvote it.

Comment: @shoover The problem is that I don't find anything actually *wrong* with the original sentence. It's phrased in an unusual way, and I proposed a simplified version, but I don't know if that deserves an actual answer at this particular site. My comment was more of a subjective edit than a real answer. (I would have provided it as an answer if it had been asked at https://ell.stackexchange.com.) Nor would an answer from me add much more than the other answer already given . . .

Comment: I don't find anything wrong with the original sentence, either. I suspect it originates from an ELL exercise for practice in rewording/paraphrasing.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion is no less ambiguous than the original; "Now it so happens that..." uses *now* as a discourse marker rather than an adverb of time, similar to the story-beginning "Now this is the way it was...". I agree that the second comma only adds ambuiguity; depending on the meaning I would suggest "As I said in my last letter, the match starts on Monday rather than Tuesday", or "The match has been moved from Monday (which it was when I wrote my last letter) to next Tuesday."

(This specific question raises a sufficiently fine and interesting point to deserve an answer, but please note that we are not a homework-answering service. Any future questions should show what research you have done, and why you are unhappy with what you have found. You might also check out [English Language Learners.SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).)